# The subgroup $O_{\pi}(G)$ in a finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

For a finite group $G$ the set $O_{\pi}(G)$ is the maximal normal $\pi$-subgroup of $G$. Could there anything said about $G / O_{\pi}(G)$?

And maybe do you know some more properties around $O_{\pi}(G)$ and some exercises around this construction?

Comment: Dear Stefan: what is a $\pi$-subgroup?

Comment: pi denotes a set of primes, and a pi-group is one such that each prime divisor of the groups order is contained in pi.

Comment: The main thing that you can say is that $O_\pi(G/O_\pi(G))=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very general, but for starters you could take a look at Rose, "A Course on Group Theory", pg. 56-58 for basics and exercises about $O_\pi$ and $O^\pi$. Throughout the book there are exercises about $O_\pi$.